# Android screenshots at a high frame rate?

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm trying to get screenshots of my Nexus 4 into my PC and I have tried all the other solutions - android-projector, droid@screen, screencast etc. and all of them give very low frame rates - 1 frame in 3-4 seconds. Droid@Screen doesn't seem to work, probably because of 64bit. I need at least 5 fps. Is there a way to get the screenshots with an increased frame rate?

Comment: I don't need a great resolution - so even if the resolution of the images is half of the phone display - it's good.

Comment: I believe screencast can do up to about 25 pretty decent depending on your device, I've used it to record video for one of my developed apps youtube videos before. I used to use it on my HTC Amaze 4G as well as my Samsung Galaxy S3, However i did purchased the premium version of Screencast

Comment: Ah, I meant androidscreencast https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/source/browse/#git%2FAndroidScreencast . I think screencast is an android app but I want something for the PC.

Comment: My apologies - i was talking about the screencast for android app for the device.